# BCP (bulk copy program) binary data c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm working with Microsoft Sql Server. I use bcp to recovery my data and it's ok. I create a binary file. 
Now I want read this binary file trought my c# application, but I have problems.
I create binary with o without \r terminator, but I have problems.
I try all web solutions (BinaryReader, convert to byte array etc...) that I find.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how *exactly* did you export the data? what is the format of this binary file? do you recall what options you used with `bcp` at the command line?

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for reply. I export two fields (int32 and varchar10) of table. I used this options: -t, -r \r -T -n